# "Tell us what your community is about in one brief sentence"

Tags: discussion, top-7, naming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/909/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/909/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

From [the SO/SE blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/):

> Instead of stressing out over the vagaries of the brutal, cut-throat .com domain market and debating the “least worst” domain name options ad nauseam, simply focus on telling the world what your community is about. Don’t even think about the domain name! Give us the one sentence “elevator pitch” for your community. How would you explain your site to a stranger you met on an elevator? It’s about … what, exactly?
>
> [...]
>
> For the forseeable future, don’t even attempt to “Pick a domain name!”. If you ask the wrong question, you’ll just get endless variations of wrong answers. The correct question, the one we should have been asking the community all along, is this:
>
> Tell us what your community is about in one brief sentence!

Comment: @fluteflute: No need to credit me or math.SE on whichever other SE site you copied it to--this question is pretty much just quotes from the blog post.

Comment: We have this on the About page: "This is a free, community driven Q&A for people studying math at any level and professionals in related fields."

Answer (score 3):

This community is about math questions and answers.